# Matlab output - Space padding?

Tags: matlab, matrix, format, output, printf

I'm trying to output a Matrix:

```
M = [1 20 3; 22 3 24; 100 150 2];
```

Using:

```
for i=1:3
    fprintf('%f\t%f\t%f\n', M(i), M(i+length(M)), M(i+length(M)*2));
end
```

And the output is turning out something like:

```
1 20 3
22  3  24
100  150  2
```

Which is obviously not great. How can I get it so the front of integers are padded with spaces? Like so:

```
  1   20   3
 22    3  24
100  150   2
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you need fprint() to write to file or something, otherwise you can just do `M` with no semicolon and Matlab formats it nicely in the command window.

Comment: I wonder if you have your preferences set improperly, so that a mono-spaced font is not used in the command window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [string formatting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq05n1r-1) to allocate specific number of characters per displayed number.
For example

```
 fprintf('% 5d\n', 12)
```

prints `12` in 5 characters, padding the un-used 3 leading characters with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) (optionally with format string `%f`) and apply it to the whole matrix instead of each row so that you get the right padding:

```
disp(num2str(M));
```

returns

```
  1   20    3
 22    3   24
100  150    2
```

Comment: @Shai If you try both, you see that `disp` adds spaces to the beginning of each line, while `num2str` doesn't and that matches the answer expected by OP.